# Navigating Between Menu items in android

Tags: android

I've a MapActivity and i want to navigate using the built-in navigation drawer to AddBook menu item but it does not navigate it's not showing any errors but does not navigate either please help.Also i want to show the marker on the current location

**MapActivity.java**

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    mMap.getMyLocation();

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    // LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
       // Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
            mMap.addMarker((new MarkerOptions().position(loc)));

        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Map Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.rajeshpantulu.bookshare/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Map Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.rajeshpantulu.bookshare/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}


public class MapActivityImpl extends MapActivity {
  public class MapActivityImpl1 extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



      // FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
      //    NavigationView navigationView;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
          Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
          setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        /*    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            }); */

          DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
          ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(


                  this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
          drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
          toggle.syncState();

          NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


          navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


      }


      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
          if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
              drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
          } else {
              super.onBackPressed();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
          // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
          // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
          int id = item.getItemId();

          //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
          if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
              return true;
          }

          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }


      //  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();



      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          System.out.println("Starting........");


          switch (item.getItemId()) {

              case R.id.nav_camera:
                  fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                  System.out.println("Getting in ............");
                  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AddBookFragment());
                  fragmentTransaction.commit();

                  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add Book Fragment");
                  item.setChecked(true);

                  Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, BookAdd.class);
                  startActivity(intent);

                  drawer.closeDrawers();
                  break;


              case R.id.nav_gallery:
                  fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new MyBookFragment());
                  fragmentTransaction.commit();
                  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Book Fragment");
                  item.setChecked(true);
                  drawer.closeDrawers();
                  break;


          }

          return  false;
      }






  }


        }


    }
```

**activity_map.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rajeshpantulu.bookshare.MapActivity" />



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"/>

</LinearLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_map"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_map_drawer" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    // actionBarDrawerToggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new AddBookFragment());
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add Book Fragment");
    navigationView= (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_camera:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AddBookFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add Book Fragment");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookAdd.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;


                case R.id.nav_gallery:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new MyBookFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Book Fragment");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;


            }


            return false;
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Can you be any more specific as to what your problem is? "it does not navigate" is not very descriptive. What have you tried to do to diagnose and solve your problem?

Comment: As in if i click on the addbook menu item it's supoosed to open up the AddbookFragment it doesn't happen .. 
I've tried using switch staments as wel las if else staments then tried giving an indent another activity which i made instead of using fragments none of them works.

Comment: Is MapActivity or MainActivity the relevant activity?

Comment: Basically the MapActivity 
It's llike for example the google maps have the navigation drawer and when you click on those menu items in that another fragment opens .. I've the similar one in my activity In the Map the navigation drawer opens but when you click on menu items it doesn't navigate.